# Chrome driver error in StartWebSession

Tags: driver

I have successfully installed the chrome driver.
By the way, StartWebSession["Chrome"] has an error.
What is the reason?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a proxy, and the setting of the Mathematica is as follows, then this problem occurs.

```
In[1]:= $DefaultProxyRules

Out[1]= <|"UseProxy" -> Automatic, "HTTP" -> None, "HTTPS" -> None, 
 "FTP" -> None, "Socks" -> None|>
```

Changing to use no proxy in the current session and future sessions will fix the failure. Remember to restore the original value afterwards.

```
In[2]:= $DefaultProxyRules["UseProxy"] = None;
session = StartWebSession["Chrome"];
(*Your code here*)
DeleteObject[session];
$DefaultProxyRules["UseProxy"] = Automatic;
```

PS: If `C:\Users\(*Your user name*)` contains non-ASCII characters, other problems may occur.